# How to extract Integer from Pytorch Tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

This is a part of code... VSCODE declares variable  > **xyxy** as **'list'**

```
                for *xyxy, conf, cls in reversed(det):
                if save_txt:  # Write to file
                    xywh = (xyxy2xywh(torch.tensor(xyxy).view(1, 4)) / gn).view(-1).tolist()  # normalized xywh
                    line = (cls, *xywh, conf) if opt.save_conf else (cls, *xywh)  # label format
                    with open(txt_path + '.txt', 'a') as f:
                        f.write(('%g ' * len(line)).rstrip() % line + '\n')

                if save_img or view_img:  # Add bbox to image
                    label = f'{names[int(cls)]} {conf:.2f}'
                    plot_one_box(xyxy, im0, label=label, color=colors[int(cls)], line_thickness=1)
                
                else : 
                    pass # 

        # Print time (inference + NMS)
        print(f'{s}Done. ({(1E3 * (t2 - t1)):.1f}ms) Inference, ({(1E3 * (t3 - t2)):.1f}ms) NMS')
        #print(xyxy_custom = xyxy.numpy()`
```

Printing variable **xyxy** gives this output **(possibly pytorch tensor)**

```
[tensor(513., device='cuda:0'), tensor(308., device='cuda:0'), tensor(661., device='cuda:0'), tensor(394., device='cuda:0')]
```

I want to extract integers from this list (for example output should be **[513,308,661,394]**

i have tried **print(xyxy.list())** or **print(xyxy.numpy()**. this gives an error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'list'
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: yes i used print(type(xyxy))... it states  unbounded | list.... I am a beginer .. donot have much idea how it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the elements of the list into integers using [`.item()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.item.html):

```py
xyxy = [int(e_.item()) for e_ in xyxy]
```